# NullPointerException null object reference Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm creating the preview for camera, I created it successfully but sometime it stretch the preview so I search on google and stackoverflow and found some solution that is getting best supportedPreviewSize from camera and show it. 
Here is some code that I'm using but there is error.
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.hardware.Camera$Size.width' on a null object reference`

I know this error is due to `null` reference, My question is way this is null ?

**Preview**

```
public class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    public Preview(Context ctx, SurfaceView surfaceView) {
        super(ctx);
        init(surfaceView);
    } 
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        this.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height); // Here is error
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onMeasure");
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
    private void init(SurfaceView surfaceView){
            mSurfaceView = surfaceView;
            final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }
    public void setCamera(){
            mCamera = Camera.open()
    }
    public void start(){
        if(mCamera != null){
            try {
                mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    // other code...
```

**MainActivity**

```
    Preview preview;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        preview = new Preview(this, surfaceView);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        preview.setCamera();
        preview.start();
    }
   // other code
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.azeem.mycamera.Preview
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Why I'm getting this error What I'm missing please let me know.

Comment: Check if mSupportedPreviewSizes is null before finding optimal preview size in onMeasure()

Comment: @AldrinMathew I'm already checking this and It's `null` my question is way this is null